# Android WebView jumping to the bottom

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` with 20 WebViews inside (yes, I know it's heavy but right now it's the best solution I've found). The WebViews are used to display forum posts.

I'm getting a very weird behavior on my Nexus 4 (it doesn't happen on some other devices I've tested) which is driving me crazy.

I have the first post visible and just a little bit of the second one visible. Now I want to scroll and instead of starting scrolling by putting the finger in the first post I put the finger on the portion of the second post that is visible. The `WebView` of that second post immediately jumps to the bottom which is a very annoying behavior while scrolling.

If you feel appropriate I can record a video of this behavior and upload to YouTube or you can search for AndroidPIT in the Play Store and check the behavior yourself in the Forum section. I won't post the link to the Play Store to avoid being called a spammer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`? Usually this has some impact on WebView functionality.

Comment: minSdkVersion=8 and targetSdkVersion=18

Comment: Have you tried setting your webview to non focusable and non clickable as it appears as it's trying to display the entire content of the item you are pressing on as you scroll (like the paragraph)

Comment: Awesome! .setFocusable(false) did the job!!! I thought that by making it non focusable that I wouldn't be able to click on the HTML links inside the webview so I actually never tried that. Please write an answer instead of a comment so that I can assign the answer to you.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad the theory worked out for you. See posted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From comment: "*Have you tried setting your webview to non focusable and non clickable as it appears as it's trying to display the entire content of the item you are pressing on as you scroll*"

Apparently [View#setFocusable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29) (`view.setFocusable(false)`) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the scrolling is handled by the scrollview in stead of the webview. I believe setting the Webview.canscrollvertically to false might fix the problem, let me know if it helped.